# How to properly layout a table, and solve words overlapping

Tags: tables, layout

as I guess you can see from the code I'm pretty new to latex tables. I want the table to look somehow like this, but I have issues with words overlapping. Do you have som tips to solve the issues, and also how you would optimally create a table?

```
 \begin{table}[htbp!]
\centering
\toprule\toprule
\caption{\textbf{Difference in Equal-Weighted First-Day Returns Between IPO Cycles}}
\label{table:7.2}

\settowidth{\templength}{\textbf{Subgroups}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{\dimexpr(\textwidth-\templength-6cm)/9\relax}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{w{c}{0.8cm}@{}w{c}{0.8cm}} @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{9}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{%
  The total sample includes 825 IPOs comprising of 171 PE, 182 VC and 472 NS. 
  The table presents the results from testing if the first-day returns across
  all three subgroups are significantly different from zero. The test is
  conducted using a two-sided t-test.} \\
\midrule
\textbf{Subgroups} & \textbf{HMA All} & \textbf{LMA All} & \textbf{HMA PE} & \textbf{LMA PE} & \textbf{HMA VC} & \textbf{LMA VC} & \textbf{HMA NS} & \textbf{LMA NS} \\
\midrule
Mean (\%) & 11 & 3 & 10 & 3 & 9 & 4 & 12 & 4 \\
P-Value & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.028} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.123} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.350} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.098} \\
\bottomrule\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

This is how the table looks:
[image]

Comment: this is not really a LaTeX problem. You are trying to squeeze the "HMA All" text into a 0.8cm cell, but depending on the fontsize it would need around 1.7cm. Reconsider your table layout.

Comment: you have provided no example but `\toprule` can only be used inside a `tabular` so I would have expected that you got errors from `\toprule\toprule`  After _any_ error do not rely on the pdf output to be usable for anything except debugging

Comment: Welcome. // Unfortunately your example doesn't even compile ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to split the titles over two row and overlap empty space.

I faked the `\toprule\toprule` using `\hrule` and `\vskip`.  I computed the maximum column width and use `\makebox` to both set the column widths and overlap the titles.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newlength{\templength}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\hrule height\heavyrulewidth\vskip\doublerulesep\hrule height\heavyrulewidth
\abovecaptionskip=1ex
\caption{\textbf{Difference in Equal-Weighted First-Day Returns Between IPO Cycles}}
\label{table:7.2}

\settowidth{\templength}{\textbf{Subgroups}}%
\setlength{\templength}{\dimexpr(\textwidth-\templength-16\tabcolsep)/8}% max column width

\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l rl rl rl rl @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{9}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{%
  The total sample includes 825 IPOs comprising of 171 PE, 182 VC and 472 NS. 
  The table presents the results from testing if the first-day returns across
  all three subgroups are significantly different from zero. The test is
  conducted using a two-sided t-test.} \\
\midrule
\textbf{Subgroups} & \makebox[\templength][l]{\textbf{HMA All}} && \makebox[\templength][l]{\textbf{HMA PE}}
 && \makebox[\templength][l]{\textbf{HMA VC}} && \makebox[\templength][l]{\textbf{HMA NS}} \\
 && \makebox[\templength][r]{\textbf{LMA All}} && \makebox[\templength][r]{\textbf{LMA PE}}
 && \makebox[\templength][r]{\textbf{lMA VC}} && \makebox[\templength][r]{\textbf{LMA NS}} \\
\midrule
Mean (\%) & 11 & 3 & 10 & 3 & 9 & 4 & 12 & 4 \\
P-Value & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.028} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.123} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.350} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.098} \\
\bottomrule\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

On second thought, it is easier to put the caption inside the tabular.  I'll let you worring about the caption skips.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newlength{\templength}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\settowidth{\templength}{\textbf{Subgroups}}%
\setlength{\templength}{\dimexpr(\textwidth-\templength-16\tabcolsep)/8}% max column width
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l rl rl rl rl @{}}
\toprule\toprule
\multicolumn{9}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{%
\caption{\textbf{Difference in Equal-Weighted First-Day Returns Between IPO Cycles}}
\label{table:7.2}} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{9}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{%
  The total sample includes 825 IPOs comprising of 171 PE, 182 VC and 472 NS. 
  The table presents the results from testing if the first-day returns across
  all three subgroups are significantly different from zero. The test is
  conducted using a two-sided t-test.} \\
\midrule
\textbf{Subgroups} & \makebox[\templength][l]{\textbf{HMA All}} && \makebox[\templength][l]{\textbf{HMA PE}}
 && \makebox[\templength][l]{\textbf{HMA VC}} && \makebox[\templength][l]{\textbf{HMA NS}} \\
 && \makebox[\templength][r]{\textbf{LMA All}} && \makebox[\templength][r]{\textbf{LMA PE}}
 && \makebox[\templength][r]{\textbf{lMA VC}} && \makebox[\templength][r]{\textbf{LMA NS}} \\
\midrule
Mean (\%) & 11 & 3 & 10 & 3 & 9 & 4 & 12 & 4 \\
P-Value & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.028} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.123} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.350} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.098} \\
\bottomrule\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```